# Howto force DashCode webapp to use Safari Mobile layout on iPhone but Safari layout on iPad

Tags: ipad, safari, mobile-safari, dashcode

A project in *DashCode* can be configure to support both *Safari* and *Safari Mobile*.

I like this dual support, but on the iPad, I found that the *Safari* layout was much more suitable than the *Safari Mobile* layout.

How can I fix the project so that on the iPad the *Safari* layout will be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyzing the code, I discovered that it is possible to force the *Safari* layout by using the following parameter ?p=desktop.

That will make it.