# Dashcode Distinguish Between iPad and iPhone Browser

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, mobile-safari, dashcode

I am trying to figure out how to get a Dashcode web application to distinguish between an iPhone browser and iPad browser. A working example of this is the [Apple iPad User Guide](http://help.apple.com/ipad/4/interface/). An iPad will display a slick dashcode built interface. The iPhone gets redirected to a web page.

I found some help in the [Howto force DashCode question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072238/howto-force-dashcode-webapp-to-use-safari-mobile-layout-on-iphone-but-safari-layo).

I am editing the redirector.js file. The following forces the iPad to use the Safari layout built by Dashcode instead of Mobile Safari, which is what I want. When it is browsed to from an iPhone, it returns a file not found error.

```
// redirect to the more appropriate product
if (DCProductURLs["mobileweb"] && DCshowiPhone) {
    // Changed case so that the Safari layout is displayed on iPad
    // window.location.href = DCProductURLs["mobileweb"];
    window.location.href = DCProductURLs["desktop"];
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately ended up using some code based on [this post at ScottRockers blog](http://scottrockers.com/blog/resources/simple-code-tricks/how-to-detect-ipad-and-redirect-to-ipad-version-website). Thanks to ughoavgfhw for putting me on the right track.

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
    window.location.href = DCProductURLs["desktop"];
}

if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) {
    window.location.href = DCProductURLs["mobileweb"];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Test window.navigator.userAgent. It will include iPad on an iPad or iPod on an iPod touch.

```
var oniPad = /iPad/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you for this. I ultimately ended up using something a little different, but your answer put me on the right track. Part of my problem was mixing up my Objective-C and Javascript. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

I modify my redirector.js file and  is doing exactly what you want, maybe is not the best way to do that but it is working, here is my code I hope that works for you:

```
var DCProductURLs = {
    "mobileweb": "../mobile", 
    "desktop": "../safari"
};

var DCshowiPhone = RegExp(" AppleWebKit/").test(navigator.userAgent) && RegExp(" Mobile/").test(navigator.userAgent);

var DCqs = window.location.search.substring(1);
if ((DCshowiPhone && DCqs.length > 0)||screen.width>1000) {
    var components = DCqs.split("&");
    for (var f = 0; f < components.length; f++) {
        if (components[f] == "p=desktop") {
            DCshowiPhone = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// redirect to the more appropriate product
//var device= 
if (DCProductURLs["mobileweb"] && DCshowiPhone && screen.width<=960) {
    window.location.href = DCProductURLs["mobileweb"];
}
```